# Java MD5 function: can someone explain me this code?

Tags: java, md5

I've found this java function that encrypt a string in MD5, but I fail to understand how it works:

```
public static String makeMD5(String text){
    MessageDigest md;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        md.update(text.getBytes());
        byte byteData[] = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++)
            sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));

        text = sb.toString();
        return text;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't understand the line just after the for loop..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `text = sb.toString();` converts `StringBuffer` object to its `String` representation.

Comment: For more info go to [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line after the for loop is a frankly overcomplicated way to convert a byte array into hexadecimal.  An equivalent, simpler approach might be

```
sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
```

though if you can use third-party libraries there are even simpler solutions.  [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9655181/869736) has a number of suggestions.

(If third party libraries *are* available, Guava will let you do this whole method in the one line `Hashing.md5().hashString(text, Charset.defaultCharset()).toString()`.)